# In TFS 2018, how do I get linked work items to show up in a release?

Tags: tfs

I understand how to link work items to a build, but when viewing release results, I see a section listed for Work Items, and that you can compare work items linked from an artifact in different releases.

What I don't understand is how to get the work item linked from a build to show up in the release that was triggered to run from the build.

How can I do such a thing?

For example, [in this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/229570/release-shows-incomplete-list-of-work-items.html), they show their build results with work items linked, and then show their release with other work items linked. What steps do I have to take to make that happen for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get linked work items to show up in a release, you just need to set the builds (show up work items) or the specific sources which associate work items with the changesets as artifact sources.

In the release summary, it compares the current release with the previous release and then displays the newly added work items associated with changesets.

Try below steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Create a build definition **A**, map sources to include the
   files/items will be changed in source control
2. Edit and modify the files/items, check in the changes with work
   items associated. (e.g. `Task1` here)
3. Trigger build definition **A** to queue a `build1` (`Task1` should
   display in Build summary)
4. Create a release definition **B**, and add build definition **A** as
   the artifact source, then create a release. (`Task1` should display
   in release summary)
5. Edit and modify the files/items **second time**, check in the changes
   with work items associated. (e.g. `Task2` here)
6. Trigger build definition **A** to queue a `build2` (`Task2` should
   display in Build summary)
7. **Do not create release here**
8. Edit and modify the files/items **third time**, check in the changes
   with work items associated. (e.g. `Task3` here)
9. Trigger build definition **A** to queue a `build3` (`Task3` should
   display in Build summary)
10. Create a release now, `Task2` and `Task3` will display in the
     release summary.

[image]