# Is it possible to link a work item to a release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We would like to link a TFS work item to a Release so we can easily, with one click  from the Release, open a TFS item that contains more info about this release. Info like Release Notes etc.

Is it possible? A release has these variables that can be set when the release is created but they won't hold a (clickable link).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We cannot link work items for an existing release for now, there's already a [user voice submitted here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13542348-in-tfs-2015-2-release-hub-allow-users-to-manually) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up or submit a new one to achieve that in future release.

However you can link work items from changeset, try below steps:

1. [Associate the work items to a changeset](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181410(v=vs.80).aspx) when you check in the changes
2. Then enable `Automatically link new work in this build` under `Option` in the build pipeline. Thus when a build completes successfully, it will create links to all work items linked to associated changes. See [Automatic linking work items to builds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/25/automatic-linking-work-items-to-builds/) for details.
3. Create a release pipeline and set the build which created in step2 as the artifacts source (***For CI/CD***).

   You can also enable `Report deployment status to Work` for the stages under `Option` in the release pipeline (***For set the repository as artifacts source***  ), thus when the stage completes, it will create links to all work items linked to associated changes.

Please note that in the release summary, **it compares the current release with the previous release and then displays the newly added work items associated with changesets**. So if you create two releases with ***the same artifacts source***, then the second release will not include the work items...  You can reference this thread for details: [In TFS 2018, how do I get linked work items to show up in a release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448882/in-tfs-2018-how-do-i-get-linked-work-items-to-show-up-in-a-release)

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use the 'Report deployment status to Work' setting in multi-stage pipelines?

Comment: It seems that I'm only getting work items from the latest build associated with my release.  I feel like I should be getting work items for all builds since the last release.  Is there any way to get this list?

Comment: FYI: The user voice link is a 404.

Comment: how to do the same using YAML pipeline?