# Is it possible to connect between TFS Azure boards to its pipeline continuous integration?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-integration, pipeline, azure-boards

I would like to connect my current azure sprint boards with different work items and tasks to azure pipeline release automation.

When mail sents to people asking for approval, I want to have more info that business users can understand e.g. TaskID, subject of the task from TFS sprint boards. Is it possible to do so and how?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to connect between TFS Azure boards to its pipeline continuous integration?

I am afraid it is impossible to connect current azure sprint boards with different work items and tasks to azure pipeline release automation.

Even we could not link work items for an existing release for now. **That because** we could **only** [associate the work items to a changeset](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181410(v=vs.80).aspx) instead of sprint boards when you check in the changes.

If you want to link workitem to a release, we could use following workaround:

- Associate the work items to a changeset when you check in the changes
- Then enable Automatically link new work in this build under Option in
  the build pipeline. Thus when a build completes successfully, it will
  create links to all work items linked to associated changes. See
  Automatic linking work items to builds for details.
- Create a release pipeline and set the build which created in step2 as
  the artifacts source (For CI/CD).

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655380/is-it-possible-to-link-a-work-item-to-a-release) for some more details.

But if you still want to connect azure sprint boards with different work items and tasks to azure pipeline release automation, this may still have a long way to do that.

If it important to you, you can submit a user voice to the development team, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22

Note: You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.